# ASP.NET Core hybrid Razor Pages / React SPA app with cognito authentication

Tags: asp.net, razor, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've got 2 apps:

-App1 that uses Razor Pages with the built in Cognito Identity middleware for authentication

-App2, built with the .net core react SPA template, uses aws-amplify for authentication in the react client and makes API calls to the .NET Core backend API using the JWT bearer token.

Both work just fine.

I'm now trying to migrate App1 to a .net core/SPA model, similar to App2.

I was able to add a ClientApp with a react app in there, and reuse most of the aws-amplify code from App2 to authenticate.

What I would like to achieve - for all the routes in Razor Pages (that have restricted access) to be accessible if the user is logged in through aws-amplify in the client.
I can achieve that just fine for API endpoints through the JWT Bearer token auth. However, trying to access Razor Pages does not work, it looks like even though my application's been configured to use JWT, Razor Pages require another type of authentication?

For reference - this is how I use the cognito JWT Bearer token to authorize access to my API endpoints:

```
private void Auth(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        var userPoolId = Configuration["Cognito:UserPoolId"];
        var userPoolClientId = Configuration["Cognito:UserPoolClientId"];

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (s, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                    {
                        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(
                            parameters.ValidIssuer + "/.well-known/jwks.json");
                        var keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWebKeySet>(json).Keys;
                        return keys;
                    },

                    ValidIssuer = $"https://cognito-idp.my-region.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidAudience = userPoolClientId,
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("xx", policy => policy.RequireClaim("cognito:groups", "xx"));
            options.AddPolicy("yy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("cognito:groups", "yy"));
        });
    }
```

My question then is - how can I leverage the cognito authentication to allow my user who logged in through AWS Amplify in the client to also access protected Razor Pages?

Thank you!